# cannot calculate mean() with dplyr()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code where I cannot calculate the last line of code (the average of top 5 values in the 17th column), which results in a warning message `Warning message:In mean.default(df[1:5, 17], na.rm = TRUE) :  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
library(eurostat)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


earn_mw_avgr2 <- get_eurostat("earn_mw_avgr2", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- earn_mw_avgr2 %>% 
    filter(geo %in% c("BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR",
                   "IT","CY","LV","LU","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO",
                   "SI","SK","FI","SE","UK"),
        indic_se=="MW_MEAGE",
        nace_r2=="B-S") %>% 
    spread(time, values)%>%
    select(-c(17,18))%>%
    mutate(avg=rowMeans(.[14:16], na.rm = TRUE))%>%
    arrange(desc(avg))


mean(df[1:5,17], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: str(df) results in ``` avg       : num  50.9 47.2 47 45.8 45.6 ...```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue is that it is a `tibble` and it won't drop dimensions as `data.frame` (where the `?Extract` would be `drop = TRUE`)

```
mean(df[1:5,][[17]])
#[1] 47.29667
```

`mean` works on `vector`s.  If we check the `?mean`

> x - An R object. Currently there are methods for numeric/logical vectors and date, date-time and time interval objects. Complex vectors are allowed for trim = 0, only.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `$avg` to `df[1:5,17]` fixes it. Full code below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


earn_mw_avgr2 <- get_eurostat("earn_mw_avgr2", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df <- earn_mw_avgr2 %>% 
  filter(geo %in% c("BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR",
                    "IT","CY","LV","LU","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO",
                    "SI","SK","FI","SE","UK"),
         indic_se=="MW_MEAGE",
         nace_r2=="B-S") %>% 
  spread(time, values)%>%
  select(-c(17,18))%>%
  mutate(avg=rowMeans(.[14:16], na.rm = TRUE))%>%
  arrange(desc(avg))


mean(df[1:5,17]$avg, na.rm = TRUE)
```